# Параметризованный класc. Возврат класса потомка

Tags: c#

Я так понимаю это сделать нельзя, но всё таки спрошу...

Есть у меня базовый абстрактный класс Control, где параметр T - это тоже какой-то класс Component, но это уже не так важно.

Я создаю потомка Button - наследник от Control.

```
public class MyButton : Control<SomeComponent>
```

В базовом классе у меня есть методы, они что-то делают и возвращают ссылку на самого себя. Бывает удобно сделать:

```
new MyButton().Text("Foo").Name("Boo")
```

Но проблема в том, я могу вернуть только Control в базовом классе.
В итоге у меня получается:

```
// 1.
MyButton btn = new MyButton();
btn.Text("");

// 2.
Control<Button> btn = new MyButton().Text("");
```

А хотелось бы, чтобы в случае варианта 2 также возвращался MyButton.

Comment: Система типов C# не может правильно выразить нужное вам ограничение. Возможно, вам стоит глянуть в сторону функциональных языков.

Comment: @VladD, так у меня ограничение (Unity3D) - только C#

Comment: Возможно, вам нужна просто Factory? Что-то такое: `var button = ButtonBuilder.WithText("Foo").WithName("Boo").BuildButton();`? (Это не совсем то, что вы спрашиваете но всё же.)

Comment: В принципе тоже вариант. Но пока решил остановиться на способе, который предложил @Athari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нормально это не поддерживается. Но есть костыль, который работает на одноуровневых иерархиях:

```
class Control<TComponent, TSelf>
    where TSelf : Control<TComponent, TSelf>
{
    public virtual TSelf Foo () { return (TSelf)this; }
    // ...
}

class Button : Control<Object, Button>
{
    public override Button Foo () { return this; }
    // ...
}
```

Если ниже кнопки по иерархии есть что-то ещё, то костыль уже не работает, к сожалению.

Как вариант, можете всегда перекрывать методы с помощью `new`:

```
class Control<TComponent>
{
    protected virtual Control<TComponent> FooImpl () { return this; }
    public Control<TComponent> Foo () { return FooImpl(); }
    // ...
}

class Button : Control<Object>
{
    protected override Control<Object> FooImpl () { return this; }
    public new Button Foo () { return (Button)FooImpl(); }
    // ...
}

class SuperButton : Button
{
    protected override Control<Object> FooImpl () { return this; }
    public new SuperButton Foo () { return (SuperButton)FooImpl(); }
    // ...
}
```

Кода больше, но иерархия может быть любой глубины.

Также есть вариант с интерфейсами, но он ещё многословнее.

Comment: Этот паттерн даже удостоился специальной статьи у Эрика: [Curiouser and curiouser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx).

Comment: Появилась другая проблема - а как объявить переменную типа Control? И условно приравнять к ней созданную кнопку, чекбокс или другой потомок?

Comment: @YShinkarev Добавьте недженериковый тип Control в корне иерархии.

Comment: @Athari, не могу понять, что надо сделать :(

Comment: @YShinkarev `class Control { ... }; class Control<T, TSelf> : Control { ... }`

Comment: @Athari, да так работает. Единственное, как понимаю не решить такой проблемы - сейчас у меня у параметризованного Control есть методы toLeftOf/AlignTo..., который принимают другие Control. Получается придётся писать в обычном классе метод с реализацией toLeftOf, т.к. условно данные с размерами, позицией есть у каждого Control и они не затрагивают специфику Component. Соответственно в обычнос Control для метода toLeftOf я буду возвращать Control, а для generic - делать new метод, вызывать метод простого Control и возвращать Self...

Comment: @YShinkarev Вы уверены, что fluent-интерфейс стОит всех этих плясок с бубном? Кстати, ещё вы можете попробовать extension-методы: `static TControl Foo<TControl> (this TControl, ...) where ... { ... return this; }` Только приоритет выше у обычных методов, поэтому имени понадобится два...